# Can you Bring Your Own IP to Akamai?

Tags: ip-address, cdn

Most clouds allow one to bring ones own IP networks. Is this also possible with Akamai or is one stuck with their networks?

Comment: Are you talking about a cloud feature like this one? https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/iaas/compute-iaas-cloud/stcsg/ip-networks.html#GUID-7299731F-7AEB-41F2-9938-2066CE7648F2

Comment: @StephenOstermiller correct.